# How to select a value for option dropdown in angularJS UnitTest

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My html code is something like this and I want to select a value from dropdown and verify the same in AngularJS UnitTestCase using Jasmine

I tried using option.value but it's not working out..

```
  <select id="company" ng-model="company" ng-change="companychange(company)" ng-options="company.ID as company.Name for company in companies"></select>
```

My AngularJS UnitTestCase is something like this
             //somecode has been left out

```
         $templateCache.put('selectcompany.html', directiveTemplate);
            templateHtml = $templateCache.get('selectcompany.html');
            formElem = angular.element('<div>' + templateHtml + '</div>');
            //console.log(directiveTemplate);
            $compile(formElem)($scope);
            form = $scope.companyform;
            companyform = form;
            form2 = $compile(directiveTemplate)($scope);
           $scope.$apply('companies=[{ Name: "Gold", value:0, ID: 0 },{ Name: "Silver", value:1, ID: 1 }, { Name: "Bronze", value: 2, ID: 2 }]');           

        }));


        describe(' company ', function () {

            it('selecting a dropdown ', function () {                                
                var options = form2.find('[id="company"]')[0];
                 angular.element(options["value='2'"]).trigger('click');

                $scope.$digest();
                console.log(options.innerHTML);
                 expect($scope.company).toBe(2);


            });
```

});

Comment: Why write a unit test for that scenario at all? You are not actually testing any javascript code you've written, but are trying to verify the way angular works with ng-model and inputs. I think there would be more value in you unit testing your companychange function.

Comment: You are right just now realised as there is no value in this test but still cant make the option to verify

Comment: Use $controller to initialize the controller where the companychange function exists. Don't worry about trying to $compile a select element. Then you can pass a company object in as a parameter and verify the expected outcome of executing that. I haven't seen what you are doing in the companychange controller to give an example or the controller where that exists.

Comment: "Why write a unit test for that scenario at all?" -  To verify that the template is correct.